# How to infer property values from arrays of objects in Typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'd like the TypeScript compiler to infer the names of properties on an object so that it's easier to invoke the appropriate functions later. However, despite considering invoking functions, TypeScript doesn't give any intellisense of the functions I can invoke.

Taking into account the following example:

```js
interface InputBase {
  alias: string;
}

const input: Array<InputBase> = [
  { alias: 'getNotes' },
  { alias: 'getComments' },
];

const client = input.reduce((acc, curr: InputBase) => {
  return {
    ...acc,
    [curr.alias]: () => {
      return curr.alias + ' call';
    },
  };
}, {});

client.getNotes();
```

My problem is really the lack of inference in the client variable, because currently the data type is `{}` despite appearing in the terminal `{getNotes: ƒ, getComments: ƒ}`.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: The compiler will not be able to follow this logic by itself, so you'll have to use at least one type assertion somewhere.  [This approach](https://tsplay.dev/mbKBdW) would be my suggestion; note that you definitely cannot annotate `input` as `Array<InputBase>` because that explicitly throws away any information the compiler has about the specific initializing value.  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?